# A random function freezing even when given correct arguments

Tags: c++, function, random, char

Here's the program that I'm trying to run:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int Generate_random(int a, int b)
{
    int n=b-a+1;
    int packet=RAND_MAX/n;
    int r;
    do r=rand()/packet;
    while(r<a || r>b);
    return r;
}
string Generate_Password(int len)
{
    string pw="";
    int least='a';
    int highest='z';
    for(int l=0; l < len ; ++l)
    {
        char c= Generate_random(least, highest);
        pw += c;
    }
    return pw;
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    cout<<Generate_Password(8);
}
```

It must be clear that I'm trying to generate a random character password (from 'a' to 'z') of 8 characters long; And the function Generate_random() doesn't works right.
I tried running some trials and found that It's getting **freezed** just because i passed least and highest(integers which are obtained from characters) I dont know how to explain this .Also , how to make it happen?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a `do-while` loop instead of just normalizing the result of `rand` to the range defined by `a` and `b`? And why don't you use the [random number genrators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) provided by the standard library?

Comment: try `r=rand()/packet + a`

Comment: Regarding your problem, you should use a debugger to step through the code line by line to see how each value changes, then you can see if e.g. the condition of the `do-while` can ever be false.

Comment: check your condition in the whille part with debugger and you see the problom

Comment: I understood, Thanks Again Everyone